# How do Android or Java get the response 'text 'message of Alexa Service?

Tags: android

https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid

introduce this App:
the app can send audio message to Alexa Service by android phone microphone ,and
response the audio of Alexa Service' Answer.

Anyone know that how to get 'text' message from Alexa Service's Answer?

Comment: The code you need is already there inside the github project which you linked to..

Comment: But  i just get the byte[] data of audio for response message .

Answer (score 0):

No you will always get the audio response from Alexa Server , you cant get the result in the form of text unless you have some Skill sets defined in the Alexa Server.